# redirecting standard output to a pipe after using exec

Tags: c, linux

so in this code snippet a process forked a child process. the child process calculated a random number r, and called linux command 'head -r "file' with an exec function which destroys the process itself, but to send the result back to the parent process the child process first duplicated the writing end of a pipe p, shared with the parent process and then closed both ends of the pipe p and closed the stdout file descriptor too...after execlp the parent process could read the result of the command 'head -r "fil2"' from the pipe p.
How is this possible?

```
        if (pid == 0) 
        {
            /* code of child */

            srand(time(NULL)); 

            nr=atoi(argv[(i*2)+2]); 
            r=mia_random(nr); //calc random value

            close(1); //closing standard output???
            dup(p[1]); //duplicating write end of inherited pipe from parent            
            close(p[0]);//closing read end of inherited pipe
            close(p[1]);//closing write end of inherited pipe

            //creating a variable to hold an argument for `head`
            sprintf(option, "-%d", r);

            //calling head on a file given as argument in main
            execlp("head", "head", option, argv[(i*2)+1], (char *)0);


            /* must not be here anymore*/
            /* using perror to check for errors since stdout is closed? or connected to the pipe?*/
            perror("Problem esecuting  head by child process");
            exit(-1);
        }
```

Why wasn't the result of head written to stderr instead? How come it was written to the dup(p[1])???

Comment: Keep in mind `srand(time(NULL))` is not really random at all, it's entirely predictable what those values will be. If actual randomness is important, avoid using that family of functions and use one that's actually random, or read data from `/dev/random`.

Comment: Why would it go to stderr?  Head writes its data to its file descriptor 1.  You arranged it so that was the write side of the pipe.  So the data went into the pipe.

Comment: You closed fd 1.  Then, when you called `dup`, it successfully duplicated the write end of the pipe on file descriptor 1.  Check the return value of `dup`.  Also, try running the code without closing stdout before you call `dup`.  Also, try the code with `dup2`.

Answer (score 1):

The system is guaranteed to open each new file at the lowest possible file descriptor.

Effectively, that means that if fd `0` and `1` are open and `p[1] != 1`, then

```
close(1);
dup(p[1]);
```

in a single-threaded process is equivalent to

```
dup2(p[1],1);
```

or in other words, if the `dup` call in this context succeeds, it will  return (filedescriptor) 1.

Comment: the best answer, thats explains it!

Comment: @Micky It's also the worst answer, since there's only one answer :D. But thanks. Please upvote/accept if you're satisfied with  it.